# How to input less than 1$ using mouse in alias: "currency" with decimals , Inputmask

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input-mask, jquery-inputmask

I`m using RobinHerbots input-mask: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

You can refer to the currency demo according to this page: http://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/ and click the demo tab, then currency.

Now to input less then $1 user needs to press or '.'
Is there a way to make it with second click on the input field on decimal, without using keyboard?
Now it works like that, if user input number firstly then he can click on decimal and input it.
Thanks for ideas, in advance.